# as3 and php variables issue

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, flash

I have a MySQL database and I access it through PHP script. The issue I have is that the variables returned from PHP are always the same.
First time I run the code (add/remove records in the database) every thing is correct, but if I'm running it again (add/remove) PHP reports back to AS3 the same records as before. running the php directly in the browser returns are correct.
hope someone can help me... I'm getting crazy!
here are my codes:

**AS3**

```
function sendSqlData(event:Event):void
{
    playlistDateString = "&playlistDateString="+playlistDate.getFullYear().toString()+monthDigit+playlistDate.getMonth().toString()+dayDigit+playlistDate.getDate().toString();
    playlistSongNr = "&playlistSongNr="+ song;
    songTime ="&songTime="+ Math.floor(channel.position);
    var phpUrl:String = "send_data.php";
    var phpUrlRequest:URLRequest  = new URLRequest(phpUrl+parseMe+playlistDateString+playlistSongNr+songTime);

    scriptLoader = new URLLoader();
    scriptLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, sendSqlDataComplete);
    scriptLoader.load(phpUrlRequest);
}

function getSqlData(event:Event):void
{
    var phpUrl:String = "get_data.php";
    var phpUrlRequest:URLRequest  = new URLRequest(phpUrl+parseMe);
    // phpUrlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

    scriptLoader = new URLLoader();
    // scriptLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
    scriptLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, getSqlDataComplete);
    scriptLoader.load(phpUrlRequest);
}
function sendSqlDataComplete(event:Event):void
{
    scriptLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, sendSqlDataComplete);
    var phpVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    phpVars.decode(event.target.data);

    getSqlData(event);
}
function getSqlDataComplete(event:Event):void
{
    scriptLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, getSqlDataComplete);
    var phpVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    phpVars.decode(event.target.data);

    var phpString = event.target.data.toString();

    var patterns:Array = ["id\\d{0,5}=\\d{0,5}", "playlistDate\\d{0,5}=\\d{0,8}", "playlistSongNr\\d{0,5}=\\d", "songTime\\d{0,5}=\\d{0,7}"];

    for (var j:int = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        var pattern:RegExp = new RegExp(patterns[j],"g");
        var tempStrings:Array = phpString.match(pattern);

        for (i = 0; i < Number(phpVars.records); i++)
        {
            switch (j)
            {
                case 0:
                    ids[i] = Number(tempStrings[i].substring( tempStrings[i].indexOf("=")+1 ));
                break;

                case 1:
                    playlistDates[i] = Number(tempStrings[i].substring( tempStrings[i].indexOf("=")+1 ));
                break;

                case 2:
                    playlistSongNrs[i] = Number(tempStrings[i].substring( tempStrings[i].indexOf("=")+1 ));
                break;

                case 3:
                    songTimes[i] = Number(tempStrings[i].substring( tempStrings[i].indexOf("=")+1 ));
                break;
            }
        }
        tempStrings = null;
    }

    fillDataGrid(Number(phpVars.records));
}
```

**PHP: send_data.php**

```
<?php
include_once ('connect.php');

$playlistDateString = trim($_GET['playlistDateString']);
$playlistSongNr = trim($_GET['playlistSongNr']);
$songTime = trim($_GET['songTime']);

if($connection)
{
    $status .= ("connect=ok&");

    //Select database
    mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection);

    $sql="INSERT INTO $tablename1 (ID, playlistDate, playlistSongNr, songTime, comment) VALUES ('', '$playlistDateString', '$playlistSongNr', '$songTime', 'comment');";
    $status .= ("sql=".$sql."&");

    // Execute query
    if (mysql_query($sql,$connection) )
    {
        $status .= ("query=ok");
    }
    else
    {
        $status .= ("query=error:".mysql_error());
    }
}
else
{
    $status = ("connect=error: ".mysql_error());
}

echo $status;
mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

**PHP get_data.php**

```
<?php

include_once ('connect.php');

if($connection)
{
    $status .= ("connect=ok");
    //Select database
    mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection);
    //Execute query
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tablename1");

    if ($query)
    {
        $result = "records=".(mysql_num_rows($query));
        $i = 0;
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
        {
            $result .= "&id".$i."=".($row["ID"]);
            $result .= "&playlistDate".$i."=".($row["playlistDate"]);
            $result .= "&playlistSongNr".$i."=".($row["playlistSongNr"]);
            $result .= "&songTime".$i."=".($row["songTime"]);
            $result .= "&comment".$i."='".($row["comment"])."'";
            $i++;
        }
        $status .= ("&receive=ok");
        echo $result."&";
    }
    else
    {
        $status .= ("&receive=error");
    }
}
else
{
    $status .= ("connect=error:".mysql_error());
}
echo $status;

mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your response is being cached when you call it from ActionScript. You can add a microtime value to the end of the URL (which will prevent caching).

```
var phpUrl:String = "get_data.php?" + new Date().getTime();
```

Comment: I tried this and I get an error: 'Error opening URL 'http://localhost/php/send_data.php1381834955078?parseMe=cameFromFlash&playlistDateString=201309015&playlistSongNr=0&songTime=0'
Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: http://localhost/php/send_data.php1381834955078?parseMe=cameFromFlash&1381834610643&&playlistDateString=201309015&playlistSongNr=0&songTime=0
 at db_fla::MainTimeline/sendSqlData()[C:\Users\andrei\Desktop\ddp_listen back prj\__new\_db\php.as:62]'. tried adding this timstamp in the phpUrlRequest, but i has the same behaviour as before.

Comment: Are you missing the `?` after `.php`? After this line, try doing `trace(phpUrl)` and see what the console shows.

Comment: the ? is included in the parseMe variable: 'var parseMe:String = "?parseMe=cameFromFlash&boohoo="+new Date().getTime()+"&";'. and this is  the console output 'http://localhost/php/send_data.php?parseMe=cameFromFlash&boohoo=1381835488440&&playlistDateString=201309015&playlistSongNr=0&songTime=0
http://localhost/php/get_data.php?parseMe=cameFromFlash&boohoo=1381835488440&'

Comment: In the `get_data.php` url in your last comment, you seem to have a `'` at the end which shouldn't be there.

Comment: now i see that the timestamp is the same, regardless of how much time I wait between the calls... why?

Comment: It looks you you define `parseMe` in a global somewhere and it only gets defined once with the timestamp. So on each other request it won't change. You need to update the timestamp in the URL on each call.

Comment: Or don't include the timestamp in `parseMe`. Just append it whenever you do `new URLRequest(....)`

Comment: and alive is as it should be :)